# Nuget Libraries - Avoid version Conflicts

Tags: versioning, nuget

we have a private nuget repo setup available for all department developers, each developers can contribute and deploy their own reusable library which gets uploaded for the entire dev team to use after few reviews.

We have a standard policy that all Libraries should be developed .Net6.

Issue here is, the developers use a random .net version, extension packages, which makes the useful library not used widely because of this version conflicts.

Is there any standard practice we can adhere to make all libraries were developed on using .net6.

Comment: I guess you simply need to enforce your policy, either by organizational or technical measures, or both, Or, when devs regularly use libs for other .Net Framework version, you may question your policy, and make sure you provide different library pools for different major framework versions.

Comment: Thanks @DocBrown for the response, is there any technique to manage library pools with single registry or a separate registry for each pool?

Comment: I have only a very vague idea what you mean by "registry" in the former comment.

Comment: when I mentioned registry, I meant the nuget server